# For loop not working on first render in useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, for-loop, use-effect

I have this issue where the *first* time my component is rendered, anything run inside a for loop (or array.map function) is completely ignored. It runs as expected the second time.

```
const myFunctionalComponent = () => {
    const initialValue = ['RU'];
    const map = useRef(null);
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(initialValue);
    useEffect(() => {
        setSelected(initialValue);
        const allPaths = map.current.container.getElementsByTagName('path'); // the array to iterate over
        Array.prototype.map.call(allPaths, path => console.log(path.id));  // ignored on 1st render ONLY
        console.log(allPaths);
        console.log(selected);
    }, []);
    return (
        <Whatever ref={map} />
    );
}
```

I tried multiple versions, including for of loops AND hardcoding my array instead of getting it with useref from a child component. It worked with a much shorter array, but this cannot be an issue, right?

I also tried converting the allPaths variable into an array instead of a collection, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized what was the problem. Instead of trying to loop through the HTML collection here, I decided to loop through it in the *Whatever* component.

This was a ReactSVG component, and I was able to perform whatever I wanted in the loop using the *afterInjection* function.

Answer (score 0):

You should define `const initialValue = ['RU'];` above the `myFunctionalComponent`. So, useEffect gets the initial value when page rendered.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that did not solve the issue. Please see my answer for the solution